# uiwebView local file html animation problems when I change viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, ios6, uiwebview

Regards Hi everyone, I have several animations created with html5 canvas, these animations the'm loading into a UIWebView which are in different UIViewControllers, when I go to a UIViewController that contains the UIWebView works perfect, the problem comes when I go to another viewcontroller that contains a UIWebView, it only shows the uiactivity indicator then goes blank, also if I'm in UIViewController that contains a UIWebView, if I leave this to another UIViewController and go back inside I have the same problem.

This is the code I am using to load the animation in the UIWebView:

```
 NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index"
                                                     ofType:@"htm"
                                                inDirectory:@"SL_03Problema/HTML"];
NSLog(@"este es el path %@",filePath);

NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[self.problemaWV loadRequest:request];

timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(loading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];



-(void)loading
{
    if (!_problemaWV.loading) {

        [_activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    }else
    {

        [_activityIndicator startAnimating];
    }
}
```

this problem as I have in ios 6.1, ios 5 works perfect

I'm using storyboard

thank you very much for your help.

Edit:try implementing a singleton class to instantiate the UIWebView once and only solved the second problem, but if I try to go from a UIView containing controler to another UIWebView, is blank the animation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some timers get into each other's way if you reload, i.e. re-schedule another timer. It does not make sense for the timer to fire every 1/2 seconds although the loading has finished.

To solve this with timers, you should invalidate the timer when the `loading` property becomes false. Make sure you keep a reference to the timer.

```
if (!_problemaWV.loading) {
   [_activityIndicator stopAnimating];
   [_timer invalidate]; 
   _timer = nil;
}
```

Sure, I think the design pattern of having a timer check every 1/2 second if it needs to update a UI element is not very good practice. Rather, you should use the UIWebView's [delegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to inform your UI that the loading is complete.